SPHINCS+ signature calculation and FORS public key
I was trying to understand the SPHINCS+ document from https://sphincs.org/data/sphincs+-r3.1-specification.pdf and have the below doubts.
Consider the example of SPHINCS+-128s , the value of n,h,d,log(t),k are 16,63,7,12,14 respectively.
This means there would be 14 FORS trees each containing 2^12 leaf nodes , so in total there would be 14 * 2^12 leaf nodes which could be chosen to sign the message by using a deterministic method.
Since there are 14 FORS tree, there would be a root for each which when combined with all others results in a FORS public key which is then signed via layer 0 leaf nodes. Now, for SPHINCS+-128s, layer 0 will have 2^54 XMSS trees and each tree shall have 512 leaf nodes , so layer 0 in total will have 512 * 2 ^ 54 leaf nodes which can be chosen to sign the FORS public key
Questions are:

FORS tree index and its leaf node index to be chosen for message signing are the same tree index and leaf index in layer 0 for FORS public key signing as Algorithm 20 in the document above uses the same in both places ? and one out of 512 * 2 ^ 54 leaf nodes will be chosen to sign FORS root of each FORS tree i.e only 14 ?
spx_keygen only generates layer 0 XMSS tree and its root, when is the rest of hypertree constructed ? is it during XMSS_sign and is the whole tree constructed or only required nodes ?
if we follow the sequence spx_keygen -> spx_sign -> spx_sign , for the second sign the FORS and XMSS trees are constructed again based on seeds calculated in keygen ?


Might I also suggest you look at the draft FIPS 205?  You might find that a bit easier to understand...

did that as well



FORS tree index and its leaf node index to be chosen for message signing are the same tree index and leaf index in layer 0 for FORS public key signing as Algorithm 20 in the document above uses the same in both places ?


I'm not quite sure what you're asking - however, this may be the answer you're looking for: there is a unique FORS tree below each of the $2^{63}$ level 0 XMSS leaf nodes.  That is, each leaf node signs a different FORS public key (and each node only signs its assigned public key).  When we do the FORS computation, we stir in which leaf node (the XMSS level 0 "tree address" and the leaf node index or "Key Pair Address") - these fields are set in the ADR structure used during the FORS computation, and so is stirred into every hash.

and one out of 512 * 2 ^ 54 leaf nodes will be chosen to sign FORS root of each FORS tree i.e only 14 ?

Well, the signature process generates $R$, and then hashes $R$ and the message (and the public seed and root) into a string of bits.  We extract bits from this string to select:

Which level 0 XMSS tree we will use.
Within that level 0 XMSS tree, which leaf node we will use.
Within the FORS that is signed by the XMSS level 0 leaf node we selected, which leaf node (out of $2^{12}$) for each of the 14 FORS tree we will reveal.


spx_keygen only generates layer 0 XMSS tree and its root, when is the rest of hypertree constructed ? is it during XMSS_sign and is the whole tree constructed or only required nodes ?

With a total of $2^{63}$ leaf nodes, it would be impractical to regenerate all of them.  So instead, during the signing process, we build only those trees that we need, that is, the 7 XMSS trees that are on a direct path between the selected FORS tree and the root (and, after the signing process is done, we discard them - we don't need them any more).
The only reason we generate the top level XMSS tree during key generation is that we need that to compute the top root value.


if we follow the sequence spx_keygen -> spx_sign -> spx_sign , for the second sign the FORS and XMSS trees are constructed again based on seeds calculated in keygen ?


Sphincs+ is stateless - that is, when we 'sign again', we do the exact same thing as we did the first time.  We use the seeds calculated in keygen (exactly the same way we did during the first signature), and when the signing process is done, we don't update any state (and so that if we sign a third time, we haven't changed anything).

1/ I get that now that there would be 2^63 FORS tree for SPHINCS+-128s. so there would be a total of 2^63 * 14 * 2 ^12 leaf nodes for the FORS layer. Correct ?

2/ and which out of these 2^63 * 14 * 2 ^12 leaf nodes would be used for signing is determined by  Hmsg(R,PKSeed,PKRoot,M). My question was that in NIST 205 Algorithm 18 , idxtree & idxleaf are commonly used for both FORS and HT signing. TreeIdx being equal is understandable, but leaf nodes is where i am confused as FORS has option to select from 14 * 2 ^ 12 leaf nodes while XMSS(at layer 0) will have 2^9 leafnodes. so how can the leaf nodes index be same for both FORS and HT signing ?

@Gappu: remember, there is a one-to-one relationship between FORS trees and level 0 XMSS leaf nodes.  The level 0 XMSS leaf node is designated by the idxtree and idxleaf; hence both are needed to uniquely identify the FORS being used to sign.

yes got it now. the nodes on FORS trees are F(SK(i)) which are used for constructing FORS public key. which index is selected depends on msg split into base b. thanks for your answer, appreciate it.
